# HuffmanTree(java)

Tags: java

The following method is part of HuffmanTree class. But It's a little different because     it's not void. I wrote the following method but It doesn't print side way. Would you please help me? Thank you!

```
 public String printSideways() {

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");

    printSideways(overallRoot, s , 0);

    return printSideways(); // I'm not sure about this part 
}

private void printSideways(HuffmanNode root, StringBuilder s, int level) {
    if (root != null) {
            printSideways(root.right, s.append(root.toString()), level+1);
            for(int i = 0; i < level; i++){
                 System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(root.toString());
            printSideways(root.left, s.append(root.toString()) , level+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting a stack overflow? `printSideways()` returns `printSideways()`.

Comment: What should the String printSideways() method return? Now it is returning itself, which returns itself, which returns itself, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `System.out.println(root.toString());` from `printSideways(root, s, level)` since you are using `StringBuilder`. Return `s.toString();` from `printSideways()` instead of the result of `printSideways()`.

Comment: the private part is void. public method should return String.

Comment: The String method should return something. We can't System.out.print for that.